react native - Create a custom curved view (shapes in react native)
I was trying to create a curved layout inside a parent view similar to a tab view with multiple tab. The first view should be curved in a way as shown in the image below. But not able to find out what exactly needs to be done.

Here is where i am stuck:
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import {COLORS, FONTSIZE, IMAGES} from '../../constants';
import {Text} from '../../components';

const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const MyTabView: React.FC = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState<number>(0);

  const handleTabSelection = (activeIndex: number) => {
    setIndex(activeIndex);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={[styles.tabBar, index === 0 ? styles.tabBarActive : null]}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={0.8}
            onPress={() => handleTabSelection(0)}
            style={[
              styles.tabItem,
              index === 0 ? styles.activeTab : styles.inactiveTab,
              styles.tab1,
            ]}>
            <Text
              as={FONTSIZE.body_m}
              numberOfLines={1}
              weight="bold"
              color={COLORS.black}>
             Text
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={0.8}
            onPress={() => handleTabSelection(1)}
            style={[
              styles.tabItem,
              index === 1 ? styles.activeTab : styles.inactiveTab,
              styles.tab2,
            ]}>
            <Text
              as={FONTSIZE.body_m}
              numberOfLines={1}
              weight="bold"
              color={COLORS.black}>
            Text
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
      {index === 0 ? (
        <View style={styles.imagesContainer}>
          {[1, 2, 3, 4].map((item, index) => (
            <Image
              key={index}
              resizeMode="contain"
              style={styles.image}
              source={IMAGES.someDummyImage}
            />
          ))}
        </View>
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.tabBody}>
          <Text>Tab body 2</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderTopLeftRadius: 12,
    borderTopRightRadius: 12,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    marginTop: -5,
  },
  tabBar: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  tabBarActive: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  tabItem: {
    width: windowWidth / 2,
    height: 56,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 12,
  },
  tab1: {
    borderTopRightRadius: 20,
  },
  tab2: {
    borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
  },
  activeTab: {
    backgroundColor: 'white', // Active tab background color
  },
  inactiveTab: {
    backgroundColor: '#E9F9F3', // Inactive tab background color
  },
  imagesContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    width: windowWidth,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  image: {
    width: 180,
    height: 92,
  },
  tabBody: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default MyTabView;

